# TableRow and TableCell class are working in web form but not working in window form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablerow, tablecell

I can use the TableRow and TableCell class in C# while using Web 
forms. The same are not available while programming with Windows 
Forms. I have the folloowing code that works fine with Web forms but 
returns error with Windows Forms. How can I make it run for Windows 
forms require any .dll to work in window form.

```
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            TableRow trBreaks = new TableRow();
            TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
            TableRow tr2 = new TableRow();
            TableRow tr3 = new TableRow();
            TableRow tr4 = new TableRow();
            TableRow tr5 = new TableRow();
            TableRow trBreak = new TableRow();
            TableRow tr6 = new TableRow();
            TableRow tr7 = new TableRow();
            TableCell td1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tdBreaks = new TableCell();
            TableCell td11 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td12 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td21 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td22 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td31 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td32 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td41 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td42 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td51 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td52 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tdBreak1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td6 = new TableCell();
            TableCell td7 = new TableCell();
```

Comment: Why do you presume that you can use webform-controls in winforms?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tim Schmelter said, I think you can't use this classes directly, because these classes are used in webforms.

Try to use another kind of control to load your data. Check this link [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/248987-equivalent-tablerow-tablecell-class) please:

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your post i had been added using mshtml  namespace and also i had added reference like Microsoft.mshtml.dll but not works getting error. @SergioR